# MySQL Update not updating anything, but Select returns results

Tags: mysql

This is truly boggling myself and my manager. Have two tables:

```
TableA (
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT '',
    foo VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT '',
    INDEX (category),
    INDEX (foo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

TableB (
    id VARCHAR(15),
    INDEX (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I run the select that I need to update on:

```
SELECT A.foo, A.id, B.id
FROM TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B
    ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.category = ''
  AND A.foo NOT IN ('bar', '')
  AND B.id IS NULL;
```

Returns ~20,000 results, returns exactly what I expect and want it to return.

But

```
UPDATE TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
  ON A.id = B.id
SET A.category='known'
WHERE A.category=''
  AND A.foo NOT IN ('bar', '')
  AND B.id IS NULL;
```

updates nothing, and

```
UPDATE
  TableA A,
  TableB B
SET A.category='known'
WHERE A.category='' 
  AND A.foo NOT IN ('bar', '')
  AND B.id IS NULL;
```

updates nothing either. No matter what we try we can't get these category fields to update.

Comment: Show us your table definition please.

Comment: @David They're just varchars in utf8 innodb tables with these rows indexed. TableB is just a single column of id's.

Comment: Howard, the reason I asked for the table definitions is If you use a multiple-table UPDATE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, update a single table and rely on the ON UPDATE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly. See Section 14.2.3.4, “InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints”.

Comment: Not that this applies here I'm sure, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Well, no wonder you're mind-boggled, so am I. Might it be something to do with NOT IN? Try AND A.foo <> 'bar' AND A.foo <> ''

Comment: Trying with <>, the multi-table update affects 0 rows and the join has been running for 2 minutes (which means it'll time out after a few hours if I let it run). Think adding a FK constraint is worth trying?

Comment: Adding indexes on the join columns is a must and a FK constraint would not hurt either.

Comment: @Hemshank you CAN NOT update a table that is selected from in a sub-query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: @David UPDATE LEFT JOIN with <> worked. Took 30 minutes to commit. Add answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no wonder you're mind-boggled, so am I. Might it be something to do with NOT IN? Try AND A.foo <> 'bar' AND A.foo <> ''

Adding indexes on the join columns is a must in any case and a FK would not hurt.

Amazed that this was the solution, NOT IN must act like a select from table subquery?? You learn something new every day, or can if you try :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfect.
Although you're seeing ~20,000 result in your select statement, but if there is nothing to update, you'll see 0 row affected.

Let's see these queries to understand this scenario.

```
-- create employee table
CREATE TABLE employee (id INT, emp_name VARCHAR(20), dept_id INT);

-- insert records to employee
INSERT INTO employee(id, emp_name, dept_id)
VALUES (1, 'ram', 1), (2, 'shyam', 1), (3, 'sita', 2)

-- create department
CREATE TABLE department(id INT, dept_name VARCHAR(20))

-- insert recrods to department
INSERT INTO department(id, dept_name)
VALUES (1, 'java'), (2, '.net')



-- update 
 -- 1st execution it will show 2 rows affected.
UPDATE employee AS e
JOIN department AS d ON e.dept_id = d.id
SET e.dept_id = 1 
    ,d.dept_name = 'dot net'
WHERE d.id = 2;


-- update (same statement as above)
-- 2nd execution (as we've already update just now will show 0 rows affected.
UPDATE employee AS e
JOIN department AS d ON e.dept_id = d.id
SET e.dept_id = 1 
    ,d.dept_name = 'dot net'
WHERE d.id = 2;
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can update in a join.....I would do an update after one or 2 query's and base it on the results etc

Comment: Of course you can update with a join.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html